# Delete all text following a tagged Content control in a table cell in Word

Tags: vb.net, vba, ms-word

Can't figure out how to accomplish this task using Word Object Model API. The code is running inside Microsoft Word Addin written mostly in VB.Net.

Here is the outline of the task in question:

Given a reference to the table cell:

1 find a tagged content control (it's going to be a single instance of that control)

2 Delete all text and new lines after that control.

3 Make sure to preserve (insert) a single new line between that content control and the end of the cell.

Edit:

```
Sub Macro2()
  Dim endOfCell As Integer
  Dim count As Integer

  Selection.EndOf Unit:=wdCell
  endOfCell = Selection.range.End
  Do While (Selection.Information(wdInContentControl) = False)
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter
    count = count + 1
  Loop

  Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter
  count = count - 1
  Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, count:=count, Extend:=wdExtend
  Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, count:=1
End Sub
```

But unfortunately this code doesn't work when integrated into VB.Net MS Word Addin solution

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service: please show us what you've already tried and detail how it's not working / at what point you're stuck. Since you're relatively new to the site you might also want to take a moment to read the guidelines in the Help Center about what's expected in a Question.

Comment: @CindyMeister. I probably can do this task in Open XML SDK or XSLT in 10-15 minutes. But so far I haven't found a way to code it using Object Model API. I tried manipulating ranges, but running into "Cannot edit range", "cannot delete a range" errors. That's why I posted the question here.

Comment: I repeat: Please show us what you've tried. And indicate the line that triggers the error. My best guess: your range included the end-of-cell markers.

Comment: @CindyMeister. I just posted the code which I plugged 5 days ago. Once again, I wasn't  expecting a someone to write the code for me. I was looking for the suggestions on the approach to take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my final (hopefully) code.

```
Private Sub CleanupTableCell(range As Word.Range)
    Dim n As Integer = range.Cells.Count
    If n > 0 Then
        range = range.Cells(1).Range
    End If
    range.Select()
    Dim selection As Word.Selection = range.Document.ActiveWindow.Selection

    selection.EndOf(Unit:=Word.WdUnits.wdCell)
    selection.Bookmarks.Add("CellBookmark")
    Do While (Not SelectionInsideContentControl(selection))
        selection.MoveLeft(Unit:=Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter)
    Loop

    selection.MoveRight(Unit:=Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, Count := 2)
    selection.Bookmarks.Add("ContentControlBookmark")
    Dim delRange As Word.Range = range.Document.Range()
    delRange.Start = range.Document.Bookmarks("ContentControlBookmark").Range.End
    delRange.End = range.Document.Bookmarks("CellBookmark").Range.Start
    delRange.Delete()
    if range.Document.Bookmarks.Exists("CellBookmark") then
        range.Document.Bookmarks("CellBookmark").Delete()
    End If
    if range.Document.Bookmarks.Exists("ContentControlBookmark") then
        range.Document.Bookmarks("ContentControlBookmark").Delete()
    End If
End Sub
```

and here is the definition of the helper function:

```
Private Function SelectionInsideContentControl(selection As Word.Selection) As Boolean


Dim controls As Word.ContentControls =   selection.Document.SelectContentControlsByTag(STR_IMergeField & "CrossComplaintPartyOneType")

    dim count as Integer = controls.Count

    if count = 0 Then
        Return False
    End If
    Dim control as Word.ContentControl = controls(count)
    If selection.InRange(control.Range) Then
        Return True
    Else 
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks. I just added the helper function definition.